# mono ./configure --host=arm-linux?

Tags: mono, arm, configure, scratchbox, cross-compiling

i tried some cross-compiling mono (2.8) with the ./configure --host=arm-linux option, running on an x86 ubuntu.

sometimes i get this error:

`checking for arm-linux-gcc... gcc

checking for C compiler default output file name...

configure: error: in mono/mono-2.8:

configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`

sometimes the configure script finishes without errors.

Idk what is now right getting the error or don´t getting it...

(edit: problem solved, seems like i did some typing errors (missing space or sth.) in the CFLAGS argument)

Is it even possible to cross-compile mono (outside an emulator?)?

best regards

Comment: without the "c compiler executables error" http://pastebin.de/15103

Comment: Not helpful. We need the failing one.

Comment: i have no logfile right now but it could be possible that i made a typing error in the CFLAGS argument. Thx for commenting.